# Is it normal for 4 chickens to spawn from one egg?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So the chickens I have laid 2 eggs. The first egg was a success while the second one was a failure.

But when I looked down it isn't one chicken that spawned, it was four.

[image]

All my other chickens were grown and 2 eggs yielded me 4 chickens.

Is this a normal Minecraft probability that is coded where multiple babies come out of an egg or did Minecraft just glitch on me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [game wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Egg#Spawning_chickens):

> When thrown by a dispenser or by pressing the use button, an egg has a 1⁄8 (12.5%) chance of spawning a chick. If this occurs, there is a 1⁄32 (3.125%) chance of spawning three additional chicks (on average, 1 out of every 256 eggs spawns 4 chicks). In other words, whenever an egg is thrown, there is a 31⁄256 chance of spawning 1 chick and a 1⁄256 chance of spawning four chicks.

Is it normal? Yes - it is not a glitch.  It is just uncommon.

Comment: Then what are the odds of 2 or 3?

Comment: @Aceplante I think it's either no chicken, 1 chicken, or 4. It can't be 2 or 3.

Comment: That does seem to be the case

Comment: For linguistic curiosity, I'm asking myself whether we can call something uncommon "normal". Hmm...

Comment: @justhalf That reasoning is part of why the preferred terminology for this type of thing among developers is not ‘normal’, it’s ‘expected behavior’.